# Excel Solver in R - Minimizing a function

Tags: r, optimization, solver, minimize

I have a (for me) pretty complex problem. I have got two vectors:

```
vectora <- c(111, 245, 379, 516, 671)
vectorb <- c(38, 54, 62, 67, 108)
```

Furthermore i have got two variables

```
x = 80
y = 0.8
```

The third vector is based on the variables x and y the following way:

```
vectorc <- vectora^y/(1+(vectora^y-1)/x)
```

The goal is to minimize the deviation of vectorb and vectorc by changing x and y. The deviation is the defined by following function:

```
deviation <- (abs(vectorb[1]-vectorc[1])) + (abs(vectorb[2]-vectorc[2])) + (abs(vectorb[3]-vectorc[3])) + (abs(vectorb[4]-vectorc[4])) + (abs(vectorb[5]-vectorc[5]))
```

How can i do this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `optim` procedure!

Here's how it'd work:

```r
vectora <- c(111, 245, 379, 516, 671)
vectorb <- c(38, 54, 62, 67, 108)
fn <- function(v) {
    x = v[1]
    y = v[2]
    vectorc <- vectora^y/(1+(vectora^y-1)/x);
    return <- sum(abs(vectorb - vectorc))
}
optim(c(80, 0.8), fn)
```

The output of that is:

```r
$par
[1] 91.4452617  0.8840952

$value
[1] 37.2487

$counts
function gradient 
     151       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

Comment: sorry robinleander, i got one more question. What do have to change if the variables have constraints?

## x < 100 & > 0
## y < 1 & > 0

optim(c(90, 0.7), fn, lower = c(0,0), upper = c(100, 1))

is this correct?

Comment: Yes! That will almost work. You'll have to switch the method to "L-BFGS-B" using `method="L-BFGS-B"` argument.